# Question about RF layout seen in application note (Texas Instruments AN043)

Tags: rf, antenna, texas-instruments

I saw the following antenna layout in a Texas Instruments application note titled AN043, Small Size 2.4 GHz PCB Antenna. What is with the right angle the feed makes? Wouldn't that cause reflections? Or is this a special impedance tuning technique (Kind of doubt that though).

[image: Application Note RF feed]

Comment: RF right next to the crystal, no guard ring or anything... eww.

Comment: @rdtsc Should not be a problem, the voltage across the signal will be a sinewave (the crystal is a high-Q resonator) so it's harmonics will be attenuated more than enough. And there **is** a ground line between crystal and RF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course the 90 degree angle will cause reflections. Anything that isn't a proper transmission line of the right impedance will.

Question is, **how much** will it reflect and **maybe it is low enough**. Many times a design might not be **perfect** but that doesn't mean it's not **good enough**. I guess in this case the designers wanted flexibility so they placed some pads to place components. And this happened to be the result.

Comment: I can attest to this. I once designed a PCB with a 90-degree, non-mitred bend on a 2GHz microstrip. Worked fine, although the performance was degraded about 5%.